# rows into columns in postgres

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.1, and I've data in the form of

```
key Name        Category
101 Lemon-Tree  Dining
101 Lemon Tree  Recreation
101 Lemon Tree  NightLife
```

and want it to present it as

```
Key Name        Categories
101 Lemon-Tree  Dining,Recreation,NightLife
```

I've tried array_agg function to group them but it didn't produce the required result..

```
SELECT key,name,array_agg(category) AS categories FROM POI_MAster_data GROUP BY key,name;
```

Is there any alternative method/function to get the required o/p?

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: Use `string_agg` instead of `array_agg`

Comment: Hi A_horse_with_no_name I tried it but looks like my version doesn't support it either....I'm using PostgreSQL 8.1.18

Comment: Another good reason to always specify the version you use - especially if it's an outdated and unsupported one. You should upgrade ***now*** because 8.1.x is really, really old. In 8.1 you can combine `array_to_string()` and  `array_agg` to simulate `string_agg()`. But again: upgrade to at least 9.2 *now*.

Comment: Check out the `crosstab` function from the `tablefunc` module. On a less prehistoric PostgreSQL version.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal choice would be to upgrade postgres to one of the recent versions (currently 9.x), which has `string_agg()`, or at least to the last officially supported 8.x branch (currently 8.4) , which has `array_agg()`.

If you really can't upgrade, you could [write your own aggregate function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createaggregate.html) in 8.1 too.